# check column for entry and then check what is next to each of those - Make a count of those

Tags: excel, excel-formula

--Edit - Solved by use of COUNTIFs --

So I am trying to see if something is possible with the below section.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ntoeJeu.png]

I want to count how many rows are "Used&Finance" and how many are "New&Finance" etc. I cannot work out how I would do so... I hope you can help.

--edit added example data--

[image: https://i.imgur.com/bmpA6W7.jpg]

Comment: I couldn't post an image as I don't have 10 reputation, sorry.

Comment: You may want to look into [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad how do I make it count if it is used and then if it is also finance in the same row.

Comment: Can you link to an image with sample data and the expected output?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad https://i.imgur.com/bmpA6W7.jpg

Comment: @Chrismas007 Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @AaronReeve `CountIfs`

Comment: @Chrismas007 perfect thanks, didn't realise it would evaluate the row, thought it would check each column individually and give me incorrect data.

Comment: Kindly close the question if it solved.

Answer (score 0):

Does the below work for you?

I9: `=COUNTIFS($H$2:$H$7,LEFT(H9,SEARCH(" ",H9)-1),$I$2:$I$7,MID(H9,SEARCH(" ",H9)+1,LEN(H9)))`

I10: `=COUNTIFS($H$2:$H$7,LEFT(H10,SEARCH(" ",H10)-1),$I$2:$I$7,MID(H10,SEARCH(" ",H10)+1,LEN(H10)))`

Comment: No countifs made it a single cell function that was simple. =COUNTIFS(Main!H:H, "Used", Main!I:I, "Finance")

Comment: That's fine that way, except that formula has hard coded words, so obviously no copy/paste is available (if you need to copy down to multiple variations that is). Glad to hear you have a solution that works for ya.